# PHP new page redirect

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is
On "Page 1", user fills a form, and when he clicks on "Submit",
a new page, say "Page 2" should get automatically created (in the same folder as index.php) in such a way that name of the page is say first_name.php (what the user filled on page 1) and it should display the contents of what he filled in on the first page. 
Something like showed in the figure.

[image: figure]

Comment: You want to create a new file for each user that outputs their details? What if you want to change the layout of the page? You should store the details (e.g. database) and have a single page to retrieve their details...

Comment: is it just me or does this sound like a really bad idea? I think flat files would be a better alternative...

Comment: @Brendan Bullen is correct. Neal explains how to do this without creating a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

showName.php:

```
<?php

   echo "    Your name is {$_REQUEST['name']}";


?>
```

This is under the assumption that your form contains an input with  `name=name`

So a form like this:

```
<form action="showName.php">
   Enter your name: <input name="name" />
</form>
```

---

Eventually you might want some validation on the submit, but for now this should suit for what you want to do.

---

### Update:

I read your question more carefully --

**You should NEVER do what you proposed** it could lead all kinds of attacks and hacks on your site.

You **could** use a mod-rewrite to seem as if the page went to `john.php` but really it is showing `showName.php?name=john`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Phil -- how does it **not** answer the question? (refresh your page i recently edited)

Comment: It doesn't create a page named `john.php` - it uses `showName.php`

Comment: @Phil -- thats because i **do not** believe that is what the OP wants to do. It makes little to no sense

Comment: Look at his example.. and the entire question, "a new page, say "Page 2" should get automatically created (in the same folder as index.php)" - it's a horrible thing to do, but that is what he is asking.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of mod-rewrite. The OP can get the URL they desire without the obvious craziness of creating a file per user...

Comment: OK cool. Bit of a PHP noob. Anyone know any tutorials on mod-rewrites?

Answer (score 3):

No, you should never do this. Say if this were off your main site, and I were to do something like "../../../etc/passwd%00" as my name, I could rewrite your etc/passwd file, or any other system file. Also, this would make you vulnerable to something called cross site scripting, also known as XSS.

Answer (score 1):

Heheh, OP, I am reiterating the advices of the above 2 posters. Never do this. He could even post a CGI exploit. Use mod_rewrite.